# Integer sequences uniquely defined by functional relations involving iteration

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Here is a generalized version of a high school olympiad problem I saw a while ago (1985 [Tournament of the Towns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_of_the_Towns), to be specific):  Find a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ (where $\mathbb{N}$ does not include $0$ here) that satisfies the relation
$$
f^{k-1}(n)=kn
$$
for some fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $k\ge 3$, and any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. (Here, $f^{k-1}=f\circ f\circ\dots\circ f$ with $k-1$ factors of $f$.) Somewhat surprisingly, the answer is unique, i.e. the initial condition can be determined from the functional relation and the fact that the function is strictly increasing. (*Aside:* If you're wondering what the function is, it is easiest to write all integers in base $k$. Consider an integer in base $k$ written as a string $jA$, where $j$ is its leftmost digit and $A$ is the rest of the string. Then $f(jA)=(j+1)A$ for $1\le j\le k-2$ and $f((k-1)A)=1A0$. This actually works for $k=2$ as well, but there it simply reduces to $f(n)=2n$, which is not very interesting.)

My question is: are there other types of nontrivial functional relations, in particular, those involving iteration, that determine an increasing function on $\mathbb{N}$ (i.e. an increasing integer sequence) uniquely without the need for an initial condition? What other types of conditions can be substituted for "increasing"? Would something like a restriction to $\mathbb{N}$ of an affine permutation of period $k$ work as well?

*Update:* It's easy to guarantee uniqueness from some point on, for example, by making the nonconstant part of the recurrence relation vanish there, e.g.
$$f(n+1)=(n-1)f(n)+1,$$
but that's not the kind of example I have in mind.